# IntelliJ IDEA User-Defined Project Template Replacing XML Values In New Project

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, web.xml

I'm saving an existing project as a template but when I open a new project using this template, it is replacing some xml values with unpopulated parameters.

This is from the original XML (path = **src/main/WEB-INF/web.xml**):

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

After I use the template to create a new project, the same file becomes:

```
<web-app version="${WEB_XML_VERSION}" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:shttp://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_${WEB_XML_VERSION_FILE}.xsdweb-app_2_5.xsd">
```

This doesn't appear to be a default parameter supported by IntelliJ, and its even inserted inline incorrectly (e.g. `${WEB_XML_VERSION_FILE}.xsdweb-app_2_5.xsd`)

Is there a way to prevent this sort of substitution when saving project templates?

Comment: Looks like a bug, please [submit to YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).